# Play Framework CoffeScript Unit Testing Workflow

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, coffeescript, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Hey guys this one is for you CoffeeScript Play!ers out there. I was wondering what your basic workflow was for Unit Testing CoffeeScript for your Play Applications. I've gotten several testing frameworks to work for JavaScript, but having a terrible time trying to figure out how to compile to CS. I tried accessing localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/app.js etc but no luck! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just encountered this problem and built an sbt-web plugin for it. Here it is: https://github.com/tanin47/sbt-web-test-js

Here are some notes

1. Integrate with `activator test`. Or you can run `activator testJs` to only run the javascript tests
2. Work with Coffeescripts for both testees and testers.
3. Generate the Jasmine-based HTML files and execute them with PhantomJS. This way you can debug the HTML files by opening them in your preferred browser.

There's another sbt plugin for this, which is [sbt-jasmine-plugin](https://github.com/joescii/sbt-jasmine-plugin), but you cannot write tests in Coffeescripts. Plus, it uses env-js which simulates a browser environment; env-js doesn't seem to be maintained anymore. IMO, PhantomJS is more robust.